# Java Script for increasing value onscroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a script in which i want to increase the margin-top of the image on scrolling down the page and vice-versa, but i cant understand where to put the event listener.

So,That when scrolling down the page, the image moves with the scroll and stops before the green div.

```js
document.getElementById("body").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);
    function myFunction() 
    {
        console.log('scrolled');
    }
```

```css
#body{
width:100%;
height:3000px;
}
#yellowdiv
{
width:100%;
height:1000px;
background-color: yellow;
}
#image
{
width:50%;
height:500px;
border: 10px solid black;
}
#bluediv
{
width:100%;
height:1000px;
background-color: blue;
}
#pinkdiv
{
width:100%;
height:1000px;
background-color: pink;
}
#greendiv
{
width:100%;
height:1000px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
    <div id="yellowdiv">
        <img id="image"src="#">
    </div>
    <div id="bluediv">
    </div>
    <div id="pinkdiv">
    </div>
    <div id="greendiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S - new to JS

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use this: `window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);`

Comment: You have attached the listener to the `body` which is also not an issue, But could please share some more details like? What you want to achieve as an output? what are the ways that you have tried?

Comment: What i wanna do is that i want to make the image increase and decrease its margin-top so that the image looks like a sticky image on scrolling the page. @kunalpanchal

Comment: so there are different approaches for this you can do it best with `Javascript`, `CSS` and `HTML`. with the css property called `position: sticky;` [Here is an Example](https://codepen.io/AndrewGehman/pen/GjBRVw)

Comment: I tried position:sticky but i think sticky doesn't work when image needs to cross one div to another div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to attach the event handler to the `#body` div but you are not scrolling the div, you are scrolling the `window`.

If you want to attach a scroll-event handler to the div, it must be scrollable. Below you can find an example with a wrapper div `#scrollable` and the event handler is attached to it.

```js
document.getElementById("scrollable").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  console.log('scrolled');
}
```

```css
#scrollable {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
}

#yellowdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#image {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

#bluediv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#pinkdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#greendiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollable">
  <div id="body">
    <div id="yellowdiv">
      <img id="image" src="#">
    </div>
    <div id="bluediv">
    </div>
    <div id="pinkdiv">
    </div>
    <div id="greendiv">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about increasing the margin-top of that image with each scroll till the green div ?